# How make dynamic collectionview cells?

Tags: ios, swift

I have that view
[image]

If i press button, add more cells with information, but it dont show because collectionview is limited of constraints.
My constraints of `collectionview`:
[image]
My constraints of stackview:
[image]
My result:
[image]

How can make dynamic collectionview cells?

Comment: Your question is not clear, r u asking for the Plus button to be on (upside of ) the collectionView..?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show dynamic cell in collection view then, why are you adding static cell and constraints? You can do using only one cell and change your content as per your requirements on every index.
And if you want to add button on bottom side then you can add using footer view of collection view.